# Import multiple csv in a DataFrame with different headers in Spark

Tags: python, r, csv, apache-spark, dataframe

i have multiple Csv which everyone r a variable like this:

cloudiness.csv

```
    +---+---+----------+-------------------+
    |_c0| ID|cloudiness|           datetime|
    +---+---+----------+-------------------+
    |  0|  3|       1.0|2013-11-08 00:00:00|
    |  1|303|       2.0|2013-11-08 00:00:00|
    |  2|306|       3.0|2013-11-08 00:00:00|
```

temperature.csv

```
    +---+---+-----------+-------------------+
    |_c0| ID|temperature|           datetime|
    +---+---+-----------+-------------------+
    |  0|  3|        3.0|2013-11-08 00:00:00|
    |  1|303|        4.0|2013-11-08 00:00:00|
    |  2|306|        5.0|2013-11-08 00:00:00|
```

..and so on, (7 o 8 o this files).

I have to merge them in one only DataFrame using Spark (R, Python or Scala) like this:

```
    +---+---+-----------+----------+-------------------+
    |_c0| ID|temperature|cloudiness|           datetime|
    +---+---+-----------+----------+-------------------+
    |  0|  3|        3.0|       1.0|2013-11-08 00:00:00|
    |  1|303|        4.0|       2.0|2013-11-08 00:00:00|
    |  2|306|        5.0|       3.0|2013-11-08 00:00:00|
```

I tried *spark.read* but it takes too much time, files are 3 GB each one. What is the best method to do it?

Comment: I would say in pyspark use the `spark.read.load('csv')` and then perform the join operation using pyspark. That is the standard way to do it.

Comment: The join takes very long time, 20 minutes at least, there's a problem with my cluster so?

Comment: There are multiple discussions here regarding Spark join performance that should help you speed this up.

Comment: @TerryDactyl seems u forgot to add the link...

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to join data frames.

when you read csv files using below snippet

val read_csv1 = sc.textFile("HDFS Path to read the file")

RDD will be created and you can join with other CSV's. If you mention performance issue means. let me give you another way.